# Count occurrences of each word in given text file

Tags: python

I'm looking for counting each word in a set of files that I'm using os.scandir to read

```
import string 
import os

d = dict() 
  
for filename in os.scandir(directory):
    if filename.path.endswith(".txt"):
        f = open(filename, encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
        lines = f.readlines()
        
for line in lines: 
    line = line.strip() 
    line = line.lower() 
    line = line.translate(line.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation)) 
 
    words = line.split(" ") 

    for word in words: 
        if word in d:  
            d[word] = d[word] + 1
    else: 
count 1 
        d[word] = 1

for key in list(d.keys()): 
    print(key, ":", d[key])
```

The problem: this prints but lists numbers which I do not want and for some reason does not calculate **the true amount** of the words in each, as the files I'm looking through are actually quite massive and there's 500+.

the result from the above is -

```
operations : 22
 : 1
10q : 5
overview : 1
highlights : 1
covid19 : 12
million : 5
2019 : 1
profile : 1
xray : 1
business : 5
consumables : 1
products : 2
35 : 1
response : 5
only : 2
follows : 1
procedures : 5
safely : 1
guidelines : 2
safety : 2
initiatives : 4
includes : 4
restrictions : 4
demand : 9
36 : 1
necessary : 2
operates : 3
2020 : 8
cash : 14
pandemic : 8
requirements : 1
drivers : 4
growth : 11
time : 7
37 : 1
developed : 1
future : 12
statements : 10
currencies : 2
```

This is missing a lot of data, and I'm just wondering where I'm stumbling that's causing this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `count 1` supposed to be doing? Was that supposed to be a comment?

Comment: Have a look into the `nltk` package.  It’s a machine learning / text processing library and has tools for just this sort of thing.

Comment: The `for line in lines:` loop needs to be inside the `for filename in os.scandir():` loop. Otherwise you're just processing the last file.

Comment: do you have an example of text and missed words?

Comment: This code finds the first text file and reads its contents into the `lines` variable.  And then it immediately does the same thing with the next file, discarding the results from the first file.  And so on.  When you get around to actually counting the words, you're only looking at the lines from the last file.

Comment: Please provide a proper mcve.  By cutting down to an input you can do by hand and using a debugger, you should be able to figure this out on your own.

Comment: you can remove numbers the same way you removed punctuation, this will though change bob10  to bob and so on. Or you can loop over result and drop all the words with numbers inside if that what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a super simple approach which makes use of the `nltk` [package](https://www.nltk.org/).

I've used built-in sample text to test and demonstrate. However, you can wrap this in a function and pass the raw text from your files into the `word_tokenize()` function, which will parse the raw text into a list. Then, pass that list of words into the `FreqDist()` class to calculate the word frequency distribution ... or, word counts.

```
from nltk import corpus, FreqDist, word_tokenize

# Test on the first 50 characters of the Inaugural Address.
text = corpus.inaugural.raw()[:50]
words = word_tokenize(text)
dist = FreqDist(words)

for k, v in dist.items():
    print(k, ':', v))
```

#### Original Text:

```
'Fellow-Citizens of the Senate and of the House of '
```

#### Output:

```
Fellow-Citizens : 1
of : 3
the : 2
Senate : 1
and : 1
House : 1
```

Comment: I appreciate this immensely! I am going to give this a try in about 45 mins - I'll update here if I run into any trouble.

Comment: How do I run this for a CSV file?

Comment: Hey @S3DEV, I'll post my workings here
`text = pd.read_csv('SECParse2.csv')
words = text
dist = FreqDist(words)

df3 = pd.DataFrame(dist,columns=['key','word'])
df3.to_csv("./SECParse3.csv", sep=',',index=False)`
What I get is an empty csv with just row headers, I'm messing something up

Comment: Hi mate.  (Sorry, different timezones).  Would you mind updating the original question with a small sample from the CSV?  I’ll update the answer to show DataFrame use, and exporting the results to CSV, as you’ve listed above.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey no problem! I was up late last night trying different things - I have a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63715192/using-freqdist-and-writing-to-csv which kind of lays out the issue to the csv. If you want to add to that I would be very grateful

Comment: @SuperAnnuated - Cool, I'll have a look.  If you'd like to accept and upvote this answer (as it was helpful to you), I'll pop over to the new question and help there as well. Also, can you update the new question with some sample content from `'SECParse2.csv'`? It'll help me build the code, specific to you. Cheers mate.

Comment: added to the bottom of the question! Appreciate the extra guidance!

Answer (score 0):

Your code loops through the files, but it only stores the contents of the last file in your var "lines", since you are updating it each time. After reading each file, call another function and pass the content as an input to that function to save memory. Don't store it and then loop through it.

```
data = f.readlines()
    for line in data:
        process(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the basic issue is that it is not correctly indented.

```
for filename in os.scandir(directory):
    if filename.path.endswith(".txt"):
        f = open(filename, encoding="utf-8-sig")
        lines = f.readlines()

        for line in lines:
            line = line.strip()
            line = line.lower()
            line = line.translate(line.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation))

            words = line.split(" ")

            for word in words:
                if word in d:
                    d[word] = d[word] + 1
                else:
                    # count 1
                    d[word] = 1
```

Also, not sure what `count` is, commenting it out works.

This worked for me.

Comment: Appreciate it, Charles! I was working on using nltk as posted by an earlier commenter. Your method however proved successful within seconds on the application.

Comment: @SuperAnnuated - Just popped an `nltk` [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63713003/6340496) on the post for you.  In either approach, I hope you find something that works for you!