# Using FreqDist and writing to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, nltk

I'm trying to use nltk and pandas to find the top 100 words from another csv and list them on a new CSV. I am able to plot the words but when I print to CSV I get

```
word | count
  52 |    7       <- This is current CSV output
```

Not sure where I am going wrong, looking for some guidance.

My code is

```
words= []
with open('SECParse2.csv', encoding = 'utf-8') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    next(reader)
    freq_all = nltk.FreqDist()

    for row in reader:
        note = row[1]
        tokens = [t for t in note.split()] 

        freq = nltk.FreqDist(tokens) 
        fd_t100 = freq.most_common(100)
        freq_all.update(tokens)

    freq_all.plot(100, cumulative=False)

df3 = pd.DataFrame(freq_all,columns=['word','count'], index=[1])
df3.to_csv("./SECParse3.csv", sep=',',index=False)
```

I'm guessing that it's my df3 line but for the life of me I can't get it to display the correct distribution in CSV

Have also tried

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(fd_t100,columns=['word','count'])
```

Some sample content from CSV2-

```
filename                    text                                     
AAL_0000004515_10Q_20200331 generally industry may affected 
AAL_0000004515_10Q_20200331 material decrease demand international air travel
AAPL_0000320193_10Q_2020032 february following initial outbreak virus china 
AAP_0001158449_10Q_20200418 restructuring cost cost primarily relating early
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. The code is quite compressed, so feel free to expand if you like.

First, ensure the source file is actually a CSV file (i.e. comma separated). I copied/pasted the sample text from the question into a text file and added commas (as shown below).

Breaking the code down line by line:

- Read the CSV into a `DataFrame`
- Extract the `text` column and flatten into a string of words, and tokenise
- Pull the 100 most common words
- Write the results to a new CSV file

#### Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk import FreqDist, word_tokenize

df = pd.read_csv('./SECParse3.csv')
words = word_tokenize(' '.join([line for line in df['text'].to_numpy()]))
common = FreqDist(words).most_common(100)
pd.DataFrame(common, columns=['word', 'count']).to_csv('words_out.csv', index=False
```

#### Sample Input:

```
filename,text
AAL_0000004515_10Q_20200331,generally industry may affected
AAL_0000004515_10Q_20200331,material decrease demand international air travel
AAPL_0000320193_10Q_2020032,february following initial outbreak virus china
AAP_0001158449_10Q_20200418,restructuring cost cost primarily relating early
```

#### Output:

```
word,count
cost,2
generally,1
industry,1
may,1
affected,1
material,1
decrease,1
...
```

Comment: My pleasure mate.  Have fun!  Any other questions, just shout.

Comment: well - I in fact do have another question - this is heading towards being a very involved project. The directory I'm pulling from has around 1,000 text files but once I get everything in order will have around 100,000. My next step is to pull the most common strings of 2 words, 3 words, 4 words 5 words, and onwards until 10 words. Can I manipulate the supplied lines for strings?

Comment: Gotcha.  You’re getting into the data science / machine learning realm. I’d strongly suggest taking a DS/ML oriented class/tutorial such as [this one offered on DataCamp](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/text-analytics-beginners-nltk).  This will give you an excellent foundation for your project.  All the best!

Comment: Appreciate it! You've been a tremendous help!